# Is it possible to make JUMflot redraw as the points are being dragged?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

The title really explains the whole thing. I would like to have the series to be redrawn live as I move the points around. I have absolutely no idea how I would even implement something like this.

Comment: No, looking through JUMflot's source code I don't see any *easy* way to implement this.  JUMflot essentially introduces three new plot events: `plotdown` (mouse down on point), `plotup` (mouse up after down on point) and `datadrop` (after drag on point).  What you need is a `datadrag` event.  It would be possible to implement this based on JUMflot, but it's non-trivial.  If I get a chance over the next day or so, I'll code something up but I'd probably roll-my-one instead of relying on JUMflot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a quick example](http://plnkr.co/edit/GHiiJzh9mGY3Bpo7YPWU?p=preview) without JUMflot, just straight flot.  Essentially it watches the plothover event and keeps track of the last hovered item.  If we hovered an item and we mousedown then we are dragging and redraw the plot on subsequent hover events.  When we mouse up, we of course stop:

```
  // a couple of globals to keep track of
  // which point did we last hover
  // which point did we last mousedown on
  var hoverItem = null;
  var dragItem = null;

  // bind the plot hover
  // if we are hovering an item mark it or null
  // if we are dragging an item, insert the new position into the data and redraw plot
  $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    hoverItem = item;
    if (dragItem){
      var data = plot.getData();
      var series = data[dragItem.seriesIndex];
      series.data[dragItem.dataIndex][0] = pos.x;
      series.data[dragItem.dataIndex][1] = pos.y;
      plot.setData(data);
      plot.draw();
    }
  });

  // when we mousedown on plot, which item did we last hover or null
  $( "#placeholder" ).mousedown(function() {
    dragItem = hoverItem;
  });

  // on mouseup we are no longer dragging
  $( "#placeholder" ).mouseup(function() {
    dragItem = null;
  });
```